# (The avoidance of) Copy mechanics in C++

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why copy constructor and assignment operator are disallowed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422125/why-copy-constructor-and-assignment-operator-are-disallowed)

I'm learning C++ from a solid C background, and in the eagerness to avoid the errors of previous C++ that I gleaned from reddit and hacker news, I've been using the [Google C++ style guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml) and LLVM's source code as references for my own code. One thing that sticks out is both the projects' use of the following code. The following is taken from LLVM's include/Support/MemoryBuffer.h:

```
MemoryBuffer(const MemoryBuffer &); // DO NOT IMPLEMENT
MemoryBuffer &operator=(const MemoryBuffer &); // DO NOT IMPLEMENT
```

Google [echoes](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml?showone=Copy_Constructors#Copy_Constructors) this usage. Clearly, it's a good thing to disable these "copy constructors".

So my question is: why are these things so scary, and (if they are not guarded against) what does their use look like and what effect does it cause in code?

Comment: Google style guide is one of the worst style guides ever written.

Comment: Without getting into your core question, do not try to learn anything from Google's style guide.  It is not intended to promote good C++, but to promote code that interfaces well with existing Google code.  Unless you work for Google, this is not a goal you should be striving for,

Comment: Try to get hold of _Effective C++_, ___2nd ed___, which is a very well-written book aimed at programmers coming from C to C++. (The newer 3rd ed was aimed at programmers coming from Java, C#, etc., so it's not as good a fit.)

Comment: @sbi: Is there something wrong with editions after the 2nd? (More for curiosities sake than anything)

Comment: @GWW: "(The newer 3rd ed was aimed at programmers coming from Java, C#, etc., so it's not as good a fit.)"

Comment: @CatPlusPlus, could you illustrate why the Google Style Guide is bad? They give rationalisations for all of their decisions, and they seem to be valid and sound arguments.

Comment: @DennisZickefoose: Similarly, why does the Google Style Guide promote a style that is any way *bad*? There's a reason that Google's code conforms to that particular guide; assumably, this reason is built off of some kind of valid reasoning.

Comment: @duane: 'init' methods. No operator overloading (and other silly overloading rules). No exceptions. Getters/setters. Out-parameters as pointers. No default arguments. No streams. No C++11.

Comment: @duane: "I'm learning C++ from a solid C background..." If that's true, then what gives you the authority to say they have valid and sound arguments? You're in no position to be making those calls. You won't be for quite some time.

Comment: @GWW: Just to confirm Dennis: The 3rd ed IMO is a great book, and better and more modern than the 2nd. Only it targets a different audience, and duane is the targeted audience of the 2nd.

Comment: @duane: What GMan said. As newbie in some field, when several highly reputed community member tell me something is bad, I would try to learn why they think so, and what they think would be better to stick to for learning, rather then trying to tell them why they are wrong.

Answer (score 9):

When an object has to manage its own resources, such as memory or a system handle, then the default copy constructor and assignment operator are no longer appropriate. That means you have to override them.

However, sometimes it doesn't make any sense to copy such an object. Or, said differently, *some objects are not meant to be copied*. Sometimes it's not even possible to write such a constructor or assignment operator. In that case, it's best to disable copy and assignment to make sure they're not copied by accident.

The standard's `iostream` are a good example.

All in all, it's a, say, special case. Definitely not something you would encounter often.

Comment: A decent example of this is objects that hold special resources such as file handles.

Comment: @GWW: or locks, or some types of smart pointers. Also, it is quite hard to avoid *some sort* of copy semantics in C++03 (how do you return objects from functions ?). Move semantics in C++11 allow you to totally stay away from copying objects if you wish.

Answer (score 6):

There is *nothing* scary about copy-constructors and they should not be viewed as such.

However, that said, there are times where copying an object simply doesn't make sense.  In the example you provided, a memory buffer is a good example of something that makes no sense to copy.  It has perhaps been used to store the data of allocated objects.  What does a copy provide?  A duplicate of the raw data of all those objects and not much else (the objects can't use it to de-allocate with, for example).

So, once we have decided that it makes no sense to copy our class, it also makes sense that we should prevent the programmer from doing it.  The compiler will be sneaky and make default copy constructors and assignment operators for us, if we don't declare them ourselves.  So, if we DO declare them (we don't need to provide an implementation) and make sure those declarations are **private**, then the compiler will issue a compile-error if the programmer attempts to do just that.

Answer (score 3):

In C++03, declaring a copy constructor and assignment operator with no definition as private is a way to prevent people from being able to copy instances of your class. If anyone attempts to do so, they'll get a compile error complaining that the assignment operator and copy constructor are private. Additionally by providing no definition if the class's own methods try to use the functions they will get a linker error complaining the operator and copy constructor are not defined. This is necessary because otherwise *the compiler will generate a copy constructor and assignment operator for you, which often will not do what you want* (a shallow copy).

In the new C++11 standard, there is a better way to do this. The delete keyword can be used in declarations like so:

```
struct NoCopy
{
    NoCopy & operator =( const NoCopy & ) = delete;
    NoCopy ( const NoCopy & ) = delete;
};
NoCopy a;
NoCopy b(a); //compilation error, copy ctor is deleted
```

Example taken from [here](http://www.softwarequalityconnection.com/2011/06/the-biggest-changes-in-c11-and-why-you-should-care/).

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes, making copies do not make sense (eg. a `std::unique_ptr`, a mutex object, or a database connection object, etc). Or making copies is inefficient, and you want to prevent this operation. Or implementing the copy constructor correctly is painful and fragile, and you'd prefer not to rely on its presence. Deleting the copy semantics is done by declaring the copy constructor private.

Another popular option is to inherit from `boost::non_copyable`.

The C++11 standard offers an alternative to the ubiquitous use of the copy constructor. This goes by the name of *move semantics*, and allows you to *move* objects instead of copying them. Move semantics pretty much always make sense: returning an object from a function moves it for instance. You can also explicitly move an object into some function taking its argument by value.

Note that C++11 in principle allows you to delete copy semantics in this way:

```
struct foo
{
    foo(const foo&) = delete;
    void operator=(const foo&) = delete;
};
```

instead of making them private, like in C++03.

Whenever I would have had to declare and implement a copy constructor, I nowadays find myself almost always *disabling* the copy semantics. With some habit, it makes sense: if copy semantics are not trivial, there is a chance that something is wrong with copying. One notable exception is *reference counting* though (see the class template `std::shared_ptr`).