# c++ Why can't I pass up types CDC and CBitmap into another class's parameters?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I am trying to setup parameter from one class into another.
But for types CDC and CBitmap, it won't let me??

dcMem and m_bmp are instance variables or the parameters in the class

(also note that I am using vc++ 6.0)

```
error C2582: 'CDC' : 'operator =' function is unavailable
error C2582: 'CBitmap' : 'operator =' function is unavailable
```

.

```
Image::Set_dcMem(CDC _dcMem)
{
    dcMem = _dcMem;
}
```

.

```
Image::Set_m_bmp(CBitmap _m_bmp)    
{
    m_bmp = _m_bmp;
}
```

I had also tried just setting the parameters as such from the other class but got the same errors listed above:

```
Image *pImage = new Image;
pImage->dcMem = dcMem;
pImage->m_bmp = m_bmp;
```

I found this links, but not sure how to apply:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ccb3dh5c%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983787%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

with the correction from down below:

```
CDC* dcMem;
CBitmap *m_bmp;

Image *pImage = new Image;
pImage->dcMem = &dcMem;
pImage->m_bmp = &m_bmp;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you assign an object using `=` the object is copied, the variable on the left is already instantiated, so it must somehow get a copy of the state of the object on the right side of the assignment.

But sometimes it is difficult to copy an object. In some cases it is because some of the internal data members of the object cannot be copied, or because it is difficult or time consuming to copy them.

In any case, when the author of a class decides that copies will not work for that class, he/she undefines the `operator=` method, to prevent users of the class from ever trying to assign objects of that class. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422125/why-copy-constructor-and-assignment-operator-are-disallowed) for some additional information on this.

But this isn't a huge problem. Normally, for objects of this kind you don't really want to be happily triggering copies of objects anyway. Instead, what you want to do is work with references and pointers.

```
class Image {
    CDC* dcMem; // <-- declare member variable as a reference
};

Image::Set_dcMem(CDC& _dcMem) // <-- pass references instead of objects
{
    dcMem = &_dcMem; // <-- you can assign references just fine
}
```

Comment: Sorry, made a small mistake. I forgot to switch the dcMem member to a pointer. It should work now.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with WTL implementation for wrapper over GDI objects because those are thin wrappers. In MFC howevre, the wrappers are not quite "thin" and in addition to GDI object handles they include private data, and are not duplicatable.

You can use references though:

```
Image::Set_dcMem(CDC& _dcMem)
{
  // ...
}
```

Comment: not working..
do I need to do something of the sort:  void operator=(const B& b){}

Comment: Working as parameter/argument, not working further as you will have to review your class code also.

Answer (score 0):

If `CDC` or `CBitmap` have reference data members, const data members, private/protected operator =, or are inheriting from such classes, then you can't apply `operator=`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't copy `CDC` or `CBitmap`. If you look at the header files you'll see that `CBitmap` derives from `CGdiObject` which derives from `CObject`. `CObject` declares a private `operator=()`, `CGdiObject` and `CBitmap` do not declare an `operator=()`, so the compiler takes the `CObject::operator=()` and as this one is private you cannot copy a `CBitmap`. (Same applies to `CDC` but with other base classes.)

You should change your `Image` class to store a reference or a pointer to a `CDC`/`CBitmap`. I'd prefer storing a reference if you can pass the `CDC`/`CBitmap` to the `Image` ctor and if the `CDC`/`CBitmap` does not change over `Image`'s lifetime. I'd stick to storing a pointer if you need to set or change the `CDC`/`CBitmap` later during `Image`'s lifetime.